# iOS pickup/import file directly from Google Drive or Dropbox

Tags: iphone, ios, google-drive-api, dropbox, url-scheme

In iOS for iPhone -iPad app do we have a facility to pick/import/copy  documents or files directly from photo library or Dropbox or GoogleDrive or any other similar kind of app in to our native application?

Or using some **url-scheme** can we directly upload it to server by just giving the path?

This kind of functionality is being provided by Google's Android OS. Do we have similar to that in iOS? Or how can we implement that?

Comment: Check document picker in ios8

Answer (score 0):

Try AMAZON S3 server to upload files and fetch files from the server and many more

Please go through the following link

http://aws.amazon.com